# $display vs $strobe vs $monitor in verilog?

Tags: verilog, vlsi, register-transfer-level

What is the difference between $display *vs* $strobe *vs* $monitor in verilog? When in the event queue does each apply, and how do the statements interact? Can any statement inhibit another?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we shouldn't have to read the manual for you. Please show what you have researched so far and still find confusing.

Comment: @dave_59 One of the reasons for the strict rules in SO is the claim that we are building up a database of questions and answers. This question seems ideal for such a database. In fact, I just Googled "verilog display strobe" (trying to be fair and thinking what someone might actually Google for) and Google invited me to add "monitor" and this page came second.

Comment: @mathew taylor, "Off-Topic" has nothing to do with whether a question is good, bad , or ideal. It's whether the topic of the question fits within the scope of the community it was placed into.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor voting to reopen. SO has millions of such questions, and they save us time.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379851/request-to-undelete-simple-verilog-question)

Comment: The fact that there are other similar question that aren't closed, on SO, doesn't mean this one should be re-opened. This question, as is, if off topic, lacks research and has no problem statement. This ___shouldn't___ be re-opened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll be nice and summarize the [LRM](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) (Language Reference Manual), but you should read it. Everything is in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 21.2 *Display system tasks* (Technically SystemVerilog, but these functions are identical.)

- `$display` : print the immediate values

  - § 21.2.1 *The display and write tasks*
- `$strobe` : print the values at the end of the current timestep

  - § 21.2.2 *Strobed monitoring*
- `$monitor` : print the values at the end of the current timestep if any values changed. `$monitor` can only be called once; sequential call will override the previous.

  - § 21.2.3 *Continuous monitoring*
- `$write` : same as `$display` but doesn't terminate with a newline (`\n`)

  - § 21.2.1 *The display and write tasks*

Example:

```
reg [3:0] a,b;
integer i;
initial begin
  $monitor("monitor a:%h b:%h @ %0t", a, b, $time);
  for(i=0; i<4; i=i+1) begin
    $strobe("strobe  a:%h b:%h @ %0t", a, b, $time);
    $display("display a:%h b:%h @ %0t", a, b, $time);
    case(i)
      0 : a = 4;
      1 : b = 1;
      2 : begin end // do nothing
      3 : {a,b} = 9;
    endcase
    $display("display a:%h b:%h @ %0t", a, b, $time);
    #1;
  end
end
```

Outputs: (notice the print order and that monitor is not displayed at time 2)

> display a:x b:x @ 0
>   display a:4 b:x @ 0
>   monitor a:4 b:x @ 0
>   strobe  a:4 b:x @ 0
>   display a:4 b:x @ 1
>   display a:4 b:1 @ 1
>   monitor a:4 b:1 @ 1
>   strobe  a:4 b:1 @ 1
>   display a:4 b:1 @ 2
>   display a:4 b:1 @ 2
>   strobe  a:4 b:1 @ 2
>   display a:4 b:1 @ 3
>   display a:0 b:9 @ 3
>   monitor a:0 b:9 @ 3
>   strobe  a:0 b:9 @ 3

Comment: The linked document is no longer available. I believe it can now be obtained from: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/servlet/opac?punumber=6469138

Comment: @icktoofay , looks like IEEE changed the link path. I've updated it to https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html

Answer (score 4):

Verilog/SystemVerilog contains a well organized event queue. All the statements in each and every time stamp executes according to this queue.

- $display executes in **ACTIVE region**, so if there is any non-blocking assignment(which executes in INACTIVE region), it won't be shown by $display.
- $write also executes in **ACTIVE region**, but an explicit call to newline character(\n) is required to insert another line. This system task is generally used when you want to display Multidimensional array using for loop.
- $strobe executes in **MONITOR/POSTPONE region**, that is, at the end of time stamp. Hence the updated value is shown by $strobe.
- $monitor displays every time one of its display parameters changes. Only one $monitor per Simulation is to be used.

Have a look at this image : [VERILOG EVENT REGIONS](http://www.vlsiinterviewquestions.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/verilog_queue.jpg)

Sample code is available at : [Display/Strobe/Monitor](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/KeL)

Hope this code makes it clear.