# Full Adder Sum Off by One Clock Cycle

Tags: verilog, modelsim, intel-fpga, quartus

I am testing the functionality of an 8-bit Ripple Carry Adder with a testbench that tries every single combination. For some reason, the sum of the current values of A and B is computed in the next clock cycle. I am not sure why that is happening.  Initially, I assumed it was because of the delays, but the error still occurs when I change the delays. Here is my code:

```
//one_adder.v

module One_adder(a,b,cin,sum,carry);
    output carry,sum;
    input a,b,cin;
    wire w0,w1,w2;

        xor(sum,a,b,cin);
        and(w0,a,b);
        and(w1,a,cin);
        and(w2,cin,b);
        or(carry,w0,w1,w2);

endmodule;


//Eight_adder.v

module Eight_adder(A,B,S,Carry);
    output [7:0]S, Carry;
    input [7:0]A, B;
    //wire [7:0]w;
    wire overflow;

    One_adder add0(.carry(Carry[0]), .sum(S[0]), .a(A[0]), .b(B[0]), .cin(Carry[0]));
    One_adder add1(.carry(Carry[1]), .sum(S[1]), .a(A[1]), .b(B[1]), .cin(Carry[1]));
    One_adder add2(.carry(Carry[2]), .sum(S[2]), .a(A[2]), .b(B[2]), .cin(Carry[2]));
    One_adder add3(.carry(Carry[3]), .sum(S[3]), .a(A[3]), .b(B[3]), .cin(Carry[3]));
    One_adder add4(.carry(Carry[4]), .sum(S[4]), .a(A[4]), .b(B[4]), .cin(Carry[4]));
    One_adder add5(.carry(Carry[5]), .sum(S[5]), .a(A[5]), .b(B[5]), .cin(Carry[5]));
    One_adder add6(.carry(Carry[6]), .sum(S[6]), .a(A[6]), .b(B[6]), .cin(Carry[6]));
    One_adder add7(.carry(Carry[7]), .sum(S[7]), .a(A[7]), .b(B[7]), .cin(Carry[7]));
    assign overflow= (A[7]&B[7]&~Carry[7]) | (~A[7]&~B[7]&Carry[7]);

endmodule


//tBench.v
//`timescale 1 ns/ 1 ns

module tBench;
    wire [7:0]sum;
    wire cin, co;
    reg[7:0] A, B;      // the different combinations
//module Eight_adder(A,B,Cin,S,Cout);
Eight_adder FA(A,B,sum,co);

initial begin
    for(A =0; A<255; A=A+1)
    begin
        #10 // the period in ModelSim: 10ns
        for(B=0; B<255; B=B+1)
        begin
          $display("A=%b,, B=%b,, Sum=%b,,", A,B,{co,sum});
         #10
            if({co,sum} != (A+B))
                $display("Error: A=%b b=%b sum=%b cout=%b\n", A, B, sum, co);
        end
    end
    $finish;
end
endmodule
```

Here is a sample output:


[image]

Comment: Why are you passing the entire carry out of your FA? Why are you using the same carry value for both your cin and cout? Why are you doing both `and(w1,b,cin);` and `and(w2,cin,b);`?

Comment: @wilcroft 1Q), Not sure why I'm doing that. 2Q) Because the carryout becomes the carryin for the all of the one-bit adders when I have then in series to make an 8-bit adder. 3Q) That should have been `and(w1,a,cin);` and `and(w2,b,cin);' I edited the code

Comment: See Greg's answer for what I was questioning in #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are computing the sum in the correct cycle, but you are displaying it at a different time.  Move the `$display` to a `$monitor` as follows:

```
initial begin
    $monitor("A=%b,, B=%b,, Sum=%b,,", A,B,{co,sum});
    for(A =0; A<255; A=A+1)
    begin
        #10 // the period in ModelSim: 10ns
        for(B=0; B<255; B=B+1)
        begin
         #10
            if({co,sum} != (A+B))
                $display("Error: A=%b b=%b sum=%b cout=%b\n", A, B, sum, co);
        end
    end
    $finish;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you are not getting only Xs for your sum output. You have the carry-out bit feedback back the the carry-in of the same adder. There should be an offset so the carry-out of one adder is the carry-in of another adder.

```
One_adder add0(.carry(Carry[0]), .sum(S[0]), .a(A[0]), .b(B[0]), .cin(1'b0));
...
One_adder add7(.carry(carryout), .sum(S[7]), .a(A[7]), .b(B[7]), .cin(Carry[7]));
```

As for your display message, your `{co,sum}` is being updated in the same time-stamp as `A` and `B`. The verilog scheduler is evaluating the `$display` before there is an opportunity to calculate anything. You can either add a delay before the `$display` (like you did with your error checking), replace `$display` with `$strobe`, or use `$monitor` before the looping. (You may want to read [display vs strobe vs monitor in verilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32832104/1959732))