# Verilog Full Adder Unexpected Behavior

Tags: verilog, hardware, icarus

I am trying to do a very basic hardware module/test bench to get the hang of Verilog. I have tried to implement a full adder.

If I am not mistaken, you have three input, immediate addends a and b and a carry in from the 2^n-1 place.

The outputs are sum and carry out (which might serve as a carry in to another module in a basic adder or whatever the not carry-lookahead is called.)

If I am not mistaken the output logic is

**sum = (a&b) | (a&cin) | (b&cin)** //or all three, which is covered by any of these

**cout = a ^ b ^ cin**

Here is the full adder module

```
module FullAdder(
a,
b,
cin,
sum,
co
);

input a;
input b;
input cin;
output sum;
output co;

//wire a;
//wire b;
//wire ci;
wire sum;
wire co;


//At least two
assign co = (a & b) | (a & cin) | (b & cin);

//one or three 
assign sum = a ^ b ^ cin; //(a & ~b & ~cin) | (~a & b & ~cin) | (~a & ~b & cin) | (a & b & cin);


endmodule
```

And here is the test bench

```
module HalfAdderTB();
reg a_in;
reg b_in;
reg cin_in;
wire s_out;
wire cout_out;

FullAdder DUT(
        a_in,
        b_in,
        cin_in,
        s_out,
        cout_out
        );

initial begin
        a_in = 1'b0;
        b_in = 1'b0;
        cin_in = 1'b0;
        #20

        a_in = 1'b0;
        b_in = 1'b0;
        cin_in = 1'b0;
        $display("a: %d, b: %d, cin: %d", a_in, b_in, cin_in);
        $display("s: %b, cout: %b", s_out, cout_out);
        #20

        a_in = 1'b0;
        b_in = 1'b0;
        cin_in = 1'b1;
        $display("a: %d, b: %d, cin: %d", a_in, b_in, cin_in);
        $display("s: %b, cout: %b", s_out, cout_out);
        #20

        a_in = 1'b0;
        b_in = 1'b1;
        cin_in = 1'b0;
        $display("a: %d, b: %d, cin: %d", a_in, b_in, cin_in);
        $display("s: %b, cout: %b", s_out, cout_out);
        #20

        a_in = 1'b0;
        b_in = 1'b1;
        cin_in = 1'b1;
        $display("a: %d, b: %d, cin: %d", a_in, b_in, cin_in);
        $display("s: %b, cout: %b", s_out, cout_out);
        #20

        a_in = 1'b1;
        b_in = 1'b0;
        cin_in = 1'b0;
        $display("a: %d, b: %d, cin: %d", a_in, b_in, cin_in);
        $display("s: %b, cout: %b", s_out, cout_out);
        #20

        a_in = 1'b1;
        b_in = 1'b0;
        cin_in = 1'b1;
        $display("a: %d, b: %d, cin: %d", a_in, b_in, cin_in);
                                                                                   2,1            4%
 a_in = 1'b1;
        b_in = 1'b1;
        cin_in = 1'b0;
        $display("a: %d, b: %d, cin: %d", a_in, b_in, cin_in);
        $display("s: %b, cout: %b", s_out, cout_out);
        #20

        assign a_in = 1'b1;
        assign b_in = 1'b1;
        assign cin_in = 1'b1;
        $display("a: %d, b: %d, cin: %d", a_in, b_in, cin_in);
        $display("s: %b, cout: %b", s_out, cout_out);
        #20
        $finish;
end
endmodule
```

My output looks like this

a: 0, b: 0, cin: 0

s: 0, cout: 0

a: 0, b: 0, cin: 1

s: 0, cout: 0

a: 0, b: 1, cin: 0

s: 1, cout: 0

a: 0, b: 1, cin: 1

s: 1, cout: 0

a: 1, b: 0, cin: 0

s: 0, cout: 1

a: 1, b: 0, cin: 1

s: 1, cout: 0

a: 1, b: 1, cin: 0

s: 0, cout: 1

a: 1, b: 1, cin: 1

s: 0, cout: 1

I believe the logic statements in my code match those of the boolean equations I wrote up top. I am confident in my logic. I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with the Verilog. Have I missed something with the timing and input of the test bench to the Full Adder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, but you are getting this strange result due to `$display` statement. Your code will work fine, if you use `$strobe` instead of `$display`. You could also use `$monitor` to display the results. The reson is that **display** statement executes immediately so that your outputs will not yet be updated with the new values, whereas **strobe** will execute only at the end of a time instant, so that your outputs would have been updated by then. **monitor** is used to automatically display values, whenever the values see a change.

Since you are just starting on verilog, I would suggest you to go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32832104/display-vs-strobe-vs-monitor-in-verilog) to understand how various display statements work in verilog and also to go through this [link](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=392278&seqNum=6) to understand the order of execution of statements in a particular time instant, so that you can plan your code better